# Partial Derivative Notation for Independent Variable

Tags: partial-derivative

assuming that $y$ is a function of $x$, would this work:

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial \dot{y}}\dot{x} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial\left(\dot{y}/\dot{x}\right)} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial y’}, y’ = \frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}} = \frac{dy}{dx}$$

Here, $y$ and $x$ are parametrized by $t$, I.e., $\dot{y} = dy/dt$, and $F$ is a function of $x$, $\dot{x}$, $y$, and $\dot{y}$.

I saw this from A First Course in The Calculus of Variations by Mark Kot.

Comment: What do you mean by $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$?  The final term, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ doesn't appear to be a function of F.  What happened to F?  Do you mean that y= F(x)?

Comment: No, F is a function of y and x. And I am using t to parametrize x and y.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the query.

Comment: Uh, where in Kot's book did you read this? It _looks_ like you're trying to rewrite the Euler-Lagrange equation, but have erred somewhere.

Comment: I think that I should re-formulate my query regarding the book in this case then. Sorry about it! Will get to it later.

Comment: Hi, I realized that in Kot’s book page 201, he made a typo; he put the wrong independent variable for the chain rule. It should have been $\dot{y}/\dot{x}$.